# How to use Netty for server to server binary websocket communication?

Tags: netty

BACKGROUND:
I have application server logic that hosts stateful object instances.  I plan to have multiple servers - each hosting stateful object instances.  NOTE: this is not a cluster with the same objects mirrored, but more of a federated model.

Each instance of my application server is using Netty and supports HTTP and WebSockets.

I wish to use the Netty WebSocket plumbing as the communication layer for not only server_1/server_2, but also for server_1/object_A talking to server_2/object_X.

For Example:

- Server_1 has objects {OA, OB, OC} and Server_2 has objects {OX, OY, OZ}
- S1:OA could communicate with S2:OX
- S1:OB could also communicate with S2:OX

QUESTION (s):

- 1) Is there a recommended approach to communicate between objects running in different servers using Netty?  Are there any examples?
- 2) Should I cache the Channel between servers and funnel all object-object requests over that?  Is this thread-safe?
- 3) OR, should I use separate Channels for server and object level communication - dynamically creating/destroying them as needed?

From a network utilization standpoint, I would think option #2 would be preferred for all bi-directional communication between Server_1 and Server_2.

If you need any clarification or more details, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send over Java classes I would recommend to use the marshalling encoder/decoder that ships with Netty[1].

To your other question, all operations on a Channel are Thread-safe.

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/marshalling

Comment: Thanks, Norman!  To follow-up on the options, am I correct in assuming 1 Channel between each respective server pairing would be recommended?

Comment: On the marshalling aspect, we don't actually need to send java objects across, but data - and we have our own binary serialization/deserialization logic.  If we're using our own binary encoding/decoding, is there a specific set of classes we should derive from when building the pipeline?

Comment: It really depends on how your "logic" is.. Maybe FrameDecoder and OneToOneEncoder, but I can only guess without more infos.

Comment: Yes one Channel is the way to go

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  As I'm cutting my teeth on Netty with this prototype, I'm sure I'll have some more questions as I dig deeper.